# Laravel API working in localhost but not worked in server while Request $request

Tags: ajax, laravel, api

**Route:**

Route::get('api/get-market-list','MemberTradesController@getMarketList');

Route::get('api/get-market-list1','MemberTradesController@getMarketListtest');

**Controller** :

```
public function getMarketListtest(Request $request){
        $markets = DB::table("markets")

            ->pluck("market","id");
        return response() -> json($markets);

    }


public function getMarketList(Request $request){
        $markets = DB::table("markets")
            ->where("exchange_id", $request->exchange_id)
            ->pluck("market","id");
        return response() -> json($markets);

    }
```

```js
   <title>Laravel 5 - Dynamic autocomplete search using select2 JS Ajax</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#exchange').change(function(){
            var exchangeID = $(this).val();
            if(exchangeID){
                $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url:"{{url('api/get-market-list')}}?exchange_id="+exchangeID,
                    success:function(res){
                        if(res){
                            $("#market").empty();
                            $("#market").append('<option>Select</option>');
                            $.each(res,function(key,value){
                                $("#market").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
                            });

                        }else{
                            $("#market").empty();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $("#market").empty();
                $("#symbol").empty();
            }
        });
       
    </script>
```

http://www.yourtradelog.com/api/get-market-list1

*below URL is not fetching data so.. my javascript are not giving me result*
[http://www.yourtradelog.com/api/get-market-list?exchange_id=+1](http://www.yourtradelog.com/api/get-market-list?exchange_id=%201) (not working)
I want to know why this is not woring on server but all are working fine in localhost

**

> ERROR LOG

**: [2](http://www.yourtradelog.com/api/get-market-list?exchange_id=%201)  [2](http://www.yourtradelog.com/api/get-market-list?exchange_id=%201): https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnPfh.png

[Composer update error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivon7.png)

[Database **markets** table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXYVA.png)

Comment: what kind of error you are getting in your console?

Comment: Please read the log file to see what happen.

Comment: i have also checked this one : http://www.yourtradelog.com/api/get-market-list?exchange_id=+1

Comment: this is laravel log : #40 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ytl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ytl/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

Comment: if anyone help me or solve it.. i can give project and also can pay for this solution

Comment: the error log you posted is just one line of the stack, you should post the entire exception

Comment: not fetching data by api on server (this is my problem).... but everything working fine in localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested the link you provided and this is my take on the situation:

1. The parameter you're sending via url has a + before the id (....=+1)
2. On your route, you're not validating if exchange_id exists (you should). If you're planning on retrieving an ID, you may call it to be in the url, or create a validation in order to check if it's correct.
3. According to your error (on [2]), make sure the route (and error page) are accessible without login (since you're not working with the csrf_token as I can see). When I send a request, I receive an empty json array, so I can't replicate that error. You can always try `composer update`

Edit: Since you say it works on localhost, have you deployed it successfully on the production or just copy-pasta?  Attention to your .env file and file permissions

Comment: Now should I do *composer update* ? because i have lot fear when update composer.  this problem is not facing in localhost but only problem in server. Localhost providing data but server can not.

Comment: localhost providing result with + and without + in url

Comment: Don't provide teamviewer information like that publicly @RajyaguruHardik .   Are you sure your database has information? On the server side. Try usind dd($request) and dd($market) to view values

Comment: actually, i dont know how to dd($request) and dd($market)...i can say that, everything is working on my localhost. i dont know what is problem... you can see above two function, Request function is not working but another is working on server